# Region of Interest opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, roi

I am trying to get a region of an image (ROI) using opencv python. The version of opencv used is 2.4.3. However when I try to call the API

```
cv2.SetImageROI
```

it returns this error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SetImageROI'
```

Also on checking the documentation it seems to suggest this api is a legacy python function.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.3/search.html?q=setimageroi

I am not sure how to go about getting the ROI using this current version of opencv in python. Could some one please suggest how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Okay, On further analysis realized that the cv2 since it has been supporting numpy array structure, there is no longer any need for a API, the entire image can be manipulated in the array itself.
eg:

```
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
img = img[c1:c1+25,r1:r1+25]
```

Here c1 is the left side column pixel location, and r1 is the corresponding row location. And img now has the image specified within the pixels as the ROI.

EDIT:
Very nicely explained here, [How to copy a image region using opencv in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084609/how-to-copy-a-image-region-using-opencv-in-python)

Comment: Look also at the answer of @Abid Rahman K here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084609/how-to-copy-a-image-region-using-opencv-in-python

Comment: That seems more comprehensive in explaination. Thanks

Comment: @AjayNair How would you crop if the region of interest is a rotated rectangle?

Comment: Here is the documentation article where it's more clear than the answer for some reason http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#image-roi

Comment: The ordering of the indices might be wrong here - I think the default Numpy index order is rows then columns

Comment: ATTENTION! Wrong order! See the example below ROI = image[y1:y2, x1:x2] - so, first rows range then columns range

Answer (score 23):

Here's a visualization for selecting a ROI from an image

```
-------------------------------------------
|                                         | 
|    (x1, y1)      w                      |
|      ------------------------           |
|      |                      |           |
|      |                      |           | 
|      |         ROI          | h         |  
|      |                      |           |   
|      |                      |           |   
|      |                      |           |       
|      ------------------------           |   
|                           (x2, y2)      |    
|                                         |             
|                                         |             
|                                         |             
-------------------------------------------
```

Consider `(0,0)` as the top-left corner of the image with left-to-right as the x-direction and top-to-bottom as the y-direction. If we have `(x1,y1)` as the top-left and `(x2,y2)` as the bottom-right vertex of a ROI, we can use Numpy slicing to crop the image with:

```
ROI = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

But normally we will not have the bottom-right vertex. In typical cases we will most likely have the ROI's bounding box `(x,y,w,h)` coordinates obtained from [`cv2.boundingRect()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) when iterating through contours

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(grayscale_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Since OpenCV v2.2, Numpy arrays are naively used to display images. This Numpy slicing method to extract the ROI may not work with older versions

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.3/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=setimageroi#cv.SetImageROI), and regarding the error message you got,  you rather need to import the appropriate module and then call `SetImageROI()` method:

```
import cv
cv.SetImageROI(imag, rect)
```