# Resize an image and only show 100x100 pixels around center

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to resize an image with cv2 so that the image is only as big as 100x100 and display it with imshow.

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Is there a function in cv2 that leaves out part of the image?

Comment: See "region of interest"<br>
([Region of Interest opencv python][3] - StackOverflow)
[3]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424852/region-of-interest-opencv-python
<br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to busybyte I found the answer:

```
img = cv.imread("PATH")
centerx, centery = [int(img.shape[0] / 2) - 50, int(img.shape[1] / 2) - 50]
img = img[centerx:centerx + 100, centery:centery + 100]
```

Which crops the image to the wanted size of 100x100 from the centre.

Comment: A minor point: you are not "shrinking" the image, you are just "cropping" the image

Comment: I meant the same, but yes no shrinking just cropping!