# How can I detect all objects in this image with a white background without merging them with each other?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

My goal is to separate all the objects from each other. After that I could use blob or detection so that I can measure the area of each one to make a Histogram with the size distribution of the objects.

Original image:

[image: original image]

The problem is that the objects are merging with each other, mainly due to their shadow and/or their proximity to each other.

Final results - bounding box:

[image: Final results - bounding box]

Binary image:

[image: Binary image]

I have tried canny edge detection, holistically-nested-edge-detection, and still having this issue.
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46174/image-shadow-removal-using-opencv-and-python) that discusses background subtraction and shadow elimination with openCV.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the box coordinates for each detection and extract the detect image based on those coordinates and then apply your filter.

Check out this post on region of interest
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211775/14770223

Comment: But using these box coordinates will add to the Region of Interest some parts of other objects, right? And if so, it will hinder more than help.