# How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python

Tags: python, opencv

How can I crop images, like I've done before in PIL, using OpenCV.

Working example on PIL

```
im = Image.open('0.png').convert('L')
im = im.crop((1, 1, 98, 33))
im.save('_0.png')
```

But how I can do it on OpenCV?

This is what I tried:

```
im = cv.imread('0.png', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
(thresh, im_bw) = cv.threshold(im, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)
im = cv.getRectSubPix(im_bw, (98, 33), (1, 1))
cv.imshow('Img', im)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

But it doesn't work.

I think I incorrectly used `getRectSubPix`. If this is the case, please explain how I can correctly use this function.

Answer (score 835, accepted):

It's very simple. Use numpy slicing.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hmm... But how i can save crop image into variable?

Comment: **remember** that x and y are flipped. I missed this.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have defined a crop margin, you can do `crop_img = img[margin:-margin, margin:-margin]`

Comment: This is great, just be aware that changing crop_img will change img. Otherwise, you should crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()

Comment: @markroxor  " x,y flipped"  thx for pointing that out ! why are they flipped?

Comment: @javadba numpy implementation detail. Numpy uses row, col notation instead of col, row

Comment: Using x, y to explain this is a little confusing, actually it is better to explain this using `axis`. In the above answer, y actually represents the first axis and x represents the second axis referring [The Basics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#the-basics). Then we can understand that like accessing the first axis and then the second. This is the same with 2D array access in Python, Java or C/C++.

Comment: I think this should be: crop_img = img[y:y+h-1, x:x+w-1]

Comment: @Froyo i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Comment: x and y are undefined..?

Comment: @Cfomodz define your x and y first.

Comment: Lol thanks @Froyo.... /s Obviously they need set first, I am saying with the given code snippet they are not, nor do they point to what they should be set to.

Answer (score 178):

i had this question and found another answer here: [copy region of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084609/how-to-copy-a-image-region-using-opencv-in-python)

If we consider (0,0) as top left corner of image called `im` with left-to-right as x direction and top-to-bottom as y direction. and we have (x1,y1) as the top-left vertex and (x2,y2) as the bottom-right vertex of a rectangle region within that image, then:

```
roi = im[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

here is a comprehensive resource on [numpy array indexing and slicing](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229114756/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) which can tell you more about things like cropping a part of an image. images would be stored as a numpy array in opencv2.

:)

Comment: Hi, Shouldn't it be ` roi = im[y1:y2+1, x1:x2+1]` under you circumstances?  Because numpy uses excluded region to slice.

Comment: @samkhan13, when I crop using this formula, all of my crops have shape (0, width, channels).  Ie. I am not getting a y dimension at all

Comment: @mLstudent33 it is likely that the image `im` has not been read correctly and is empty. try using an IDE with breakpoints to diagnose your code step by step. you can use [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) to create code blocks and can share your jupytor notebook on [stackoverflow python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to get someones help.

Comment: @samkhan13 actually I have a weird issue that I posted on Github Opencv Issues:  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15406 I'll check out chat as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

This code crops an image from x=0,y=0 to h=100,w=200.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('download.jpg')
y=0
x=0
h=100
w=200
crop = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('Image', crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: @hatami, so height is 100 pixels "below" y = 0 right?  It is the 101st row of the numpy array?  And width is 200 pixels to the right of x =0 correct?

Comment: Kudos for using variable names that can actually be understood.

Answer (score 24):

Note that, image slicing is not creating a copy of the `cropped image` but creating a `pointer` to the `roi`. If you are loading so many images, cropping the relevant parts of the images with slicing, then appending into a list, this might be a huge memory waste.

Suppose you load N images each is `>1MP` and you need only `100x100` region from the upper left corner.

`Slicing`:

```
X = []
for i in range(N):
    im = imread('image_i')
    X.append(im[0:100,0:100]) # This will keep all N images in the memory. 
                              # Because they are still used.
```

Alternatively, you can copy the relevant part by `.copy()`, so garbage collector will remove `im`.

```
X = []
for i in range(N):
    im = imread('image_i')
    X.append(im[0:100,0:100].copy()) # This will keep only the crops in the memory. 
                                     # im's will be deleted by gc.
```

After finding out this, I realized [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python#comment92938795_15589825) by [user1270710](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270710/user1270710) mentioned that but it took me quite some time to find out (i.e., debugging etc). So, I think it worths mentioning.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60359398/7644562

Comment: In mean of memory space occupied, I understand that copying the region of interest is the best thing to do, but what about time consuming ? If i do `copy()` the ROI, compared to slicing, what would be the result ?. Also, If I have a variable `tmp` in which I store each picture I load from my computer, the slicing shouldn't have a bad impact on my memory, right? _The problem you describe is only related to what happens when you load all images and then you store again them ROI, having both the originals and the ROI_ . **Please let me know if I did understand right.**

Comment: Copying will be negligible time in the case I said. Unless you copy large images so many times, you won't have a time difference. In my code, the effect will be like less than 1ms per cropping. The problem is you either store the large image and a pointer(ROI which is only few bytes) or you store a small image in memory(in my case). If you do this a few times, it is fine. However if you do this thousands of times, memory usage will be crazy with slicing. Like you fill the entire memory after a couple if thousand image loading if you do slicing. Whereas my code will still be on the order if MBs

Answer (score 7):

here is some code for more robust imcrop ( a bit like in matlab )

```
def imcrop(img, bbox): 
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = bbox
    if x1 < 0 or y1 < 0 or x2 > img.shape[1] or y2 > img.shape[0]:
        img, x1, x2, y1, y2 = pad_img_to_fit_bbox(img, x1, x2, y1, y2)
    return img[y1:y2, x1:x2, :]

def pad_img_to_fit_bbox(img, x1, x2, y1, y2):
    img = np.pad(img, ((np.abs(np.minimum(0, y1)), np.maximum(y2 - img.shape[0], 0)),
               (np.abs(np.minimum(0, x1)), np.maximum(x2 - img.shape[1], 0)), (0,0)), mode="constant")
    y1 += np.abs(np.minimum(0, y1))
    y2 += np.abs(np.minimum(0, y1))
    x1 += np.abs(np.minimum(0, x1))
    x2 += np.abs(np.minimum(0, x1))
    return img, x1, x2, y1, y2
```

Comment: There's a bug in this in that you need to do the += on y2 before y1 and x2 before x1.  Alternatively calculate the padY = np.abs(np.minimum(0, y1) and just have y1 += padY and y2 += padY.

Answer (score 7):

Robust crop with opencv copy border function:

```
def imcrop(img, bbox):
   x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
   if x1 < 0 or y1 < 0 or x2 > img.shape[1] or y2 > img.shape[0]:
        img, x1, x2, y1, y2 = pad_img_to_fit_bbox(img, x1, x2, y1, y2)
   return img[y1:y2, x1:x2, :]

def pad_img_to_fit_bbox(img, x1, x2, y1, y2):
    img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, - min(0, y1), max(y2 - img.shape[0], 0),
                            -min(0, x1), max(x2 - img.shape[1], 0),cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
   y2 += -min(0, y1)
   y1 += -min(0, y1)
   x2 += -min(0, x1)
   x1 += -min(0, x1)
   return img, x1, x2, y1, y2
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is bbox here and what are we supposed to give in its value because whatever value I'm trying to pass, it is giving me error on 

`x1,y1,x2,y2 = bbox`

while saying: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @sabah It is supposed to be a tuple or list with 4 values. If you define bbox as a single integer you will get an error

Answer (score 7):

Below is the way to crop an image.

**image_path:** The path to the image to edit

**coords:** A tuple of x/y coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2)[open the image in 
mspaint and check the "ruler" in view tab to see the coordinates]

**saved_location**: Path to save the cropped image

```
from PIL import Image
    def crop(image_path, coords, saved_location:
        image_obj = Image.open("Path of the image to be cropped")
            cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)
            cropped_image.save(saved_location)
            cropped_image.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = "image.jpg"
    crop(image, (100, 210, 710,380 ), 'cropped.jpg')
```

Answer (score 3):

to make it easier for you here is the code that i use :

```
    top=514
    right=430
    height= 40
    width=100
    croped_image = image[top : (top + height) , right: (right + width)]
    plt.imshow(croped_image, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

to crop or region of interest(ROI) for face use below code

```
import cv2 
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
image=cv2.imread("ronaldo.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
     cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2) 
     roi_image = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("crop/region of interset image",roi_image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[check for reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-python-program-face-detection/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use tensorflow for the cropping and openCV for making an array from the image.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('YOURIMAGE.png')
```

Now `img` is a (imageheight, imagewidth, 3) shape array. Crop the array with tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
offset_height=0
offset_width=0
target_height=500
target_width=500
x = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
    img, offset_height, offset_width, target_height, target_width
)
```

Reassemble the image with tf.keras, so we can look at it if it worked:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
    x, data_format=None, scale=True, dtype=None
)
```

This prints out the pic in a notebook (tested in Google Colab).

---

The whole code together:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('YOURIMAGE.png')

import tensorflow as tf
offset_height=0
offset_width=0
target_height=500
target_width=500
x = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
    img, offset_height, offset_width, target_height, target_width
)

tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
    x, data_format=None, scale=True, dtype=None
)
```

Answer (score -1):

By using this function you can easily crop image

```
def cropImage(Image, XY: tuple, WH: tuple, returnGrayscale=False):
    # Extract the x,y and w,h values
    (x, y) = XY
    (w, h) = WH
    # Crop Image with numpy splitting
    crop = Image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    # Check if returnGrayscale Var is true if is then convert image to grayscale
    if returnGrayscale:
        crop = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Return cropped image
    return crop
```

**HOPE THIS HELPS**

Answer (score -1):

```
# Import packages
import cv2

import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('skewness.png')
print(img.shape) # Print image shape

cv2.imshow("original", img)

# Cropping an image
cropped_image = img[80:280, 150:330]
 
# Display cropped image
cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped_image)

# Save the cropped image
cv2.imwrite("Cropped Image.jpg", cropped_image)

#The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when \f$\texttt{delay}\leq 0\f$ ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive
cv2.waitKey(0)

#The function destroyAllWindows destroys all of the opened HighGUI windows.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```