# Python opencv crop not working

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, crop

I am relatively new to OpenCV. I have gleaned from tutorials and such that you can crop by using this script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import video

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,vis = cam.read()    
crop = vis[100:400, 100:300]    
cv2.imshow("Img",vis)
cv2.imshow("Crop",crop)    
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And this works fine. I get no errors.

However, when i put it into my main script, it doesn't work, i've narrowed it down to this section of code:

```
def PicTake(self):
    ret,vis = self.cam.read()
    x1,y1 = self.selection[0]
    x2,y2 = self.selection[1]
    a = 0
    taken = 0
    while taken == 0:
        if cv2.imread("C:\Python27\opencv\samples\python2\Major\Test"+str(a)+".png") == None:
            crop = vis[x1:y1, x2:y2]
            print crop
            cv2.imshow("crop",crop)
            cv2.imwrite("C:\Python27\opencv\samples\python2\Major\Test"+str(a)+".png",crop)
            taken = 1
        else:
            a+=1
    return ("Picture Taken")
```

where self.selection is just a list of two tuples [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]. After the first if statement, print crop returns "[]" and empty list.

So yeah, why does it work with numbers and other situations fine, but not here?!

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are the values of [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]?

Comment: My code for getting the values is:

`def onmouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
     self.onwindow = 1 # Mouse is on screen
     x,y = np.int16([x, y]) # BUG
     self.currentxy = (x,y)
     if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
         self.RectOn = 0 #Del old rectangle and make new one
         self.click = 1
         self.x1y1 = (x,y)
         self.selection[0] = self.x1y1
         self.selection[1] = (0,0)
     if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
         self.click = 0
         self.x2y2 = (x,y)
         self.selection[1] = self.x2y2
         self.RectOn = 1
         print self.selection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vis` is just a `numpy` array.
Check the result of `print vis.shape` to check the dimensions of your input image.
In case of a color image this would be something like this:

```
(367, 550, 3)
```

Which represents the dimensions in the order of `height`, `width` and then `color depth`.
So, if you want to select a portion from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) when x2>x1 and y2>y1:

```
vis[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

and this would also cover the depth dimension too.
Note that if `y2<y1` or `x2<x1`, the result would be an empty array.

Comment: Thank you! It's working, I had the `[y1:y2, x1:x2]` the opposite way. And your right, I have to do something about the two points being selected in different positions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
crop = vis[y1:y2,x1:x2]
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16823104/1463143) to get a detailed explanation.

also check to see if the camera actually outputted anything. after the line

```
ret, vis = self.cam.read()
```

add these lines

```
if not ret:
 print 'No captured images'
```

Answer (score 0):

Croping can be very confusing.  The CV world runs on corner pairs (X1,Y1), while python is working by slicing arrays.  A correct cropping might look like:

crop = original[y1:y2, x1:x2]  # pay attention to your Y's and X's