# NumPy slicing of an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, crop

I have been looking to copy an image over another[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python).

I wrote a very simple python function:

```
def fromCopyTo(target, destination, x, y):
    h, w = target.shape

    destination[y:y+h,x:x+w] = target

    return destination
```

the concept is to get an **target** image and **X** and **Y** coordinates and copy the **target** image to that **position** - without thinking of the size of the target image (assume the **destination** image is big enough)

I am using an empty mask to copy to and trying to copy an image with a size *20x20* - the **target** image is only *(0,0,0)* and *(255,255,255)* colors

the problem is that **y:y+h,** returns maximum of size 11 rather than the size 20.

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into
>   shape (11,20)

if I flip the function `destination[x:x+w, y:y+h] = target` (which as far as I understand is wrong) I get:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into
>   shape (20,0)

by testing I ran `print len(destination[y_position:y_position+30, 0])` which returns everything up to **11** but after **11** it just maxes it out to **11**. As the example returns **11**.

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I try to cut more than there is available in the **mask** matrix I do not get an error message saying I am overflowing, but rather than that it just limits it to the maximum possible size.