# How can I automatically save and crop a produced image?

Tags: python, image, face-detection

I'm using [FaceDetect](https://github.com/shantnu/FaceDetect/) (Python) which finds a face in an image and creates a box around it (as below).

Unlike the image below, the images I want to use all have a single face. Is there a simple way to save the produced image and crop it to what is inside the box?

[image]

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/? This explains how the example works. You could also try reading the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 26 on face_detect.py  - Looks like it has the dimensions you need...

```
# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

You need to replace the `rectangle()` function with logic to crop instead.  You should be able to pass in the dimensions into a numpy array function to do the crop.  Here's an example of cropping in OpenCV using hard coded dimensions...

[How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)