# Trim mask area from image (crop)

Tags: python, opencv

I managed to generate a mask from a PNG transparent image and to use it in order to generate a transparent area on another photo.

This is my photo:
[image]

This is the image that I use for generating the mask (is a frame with transparent area):
[image]

After some resize to match the size of the picture the mask is:
[image]

And the final result is:
[image]

This is almost perfect because I have the original picture and the area covered by the masked became transparent but I need to have just the corners transparent without the border.

I want to trim/crop a rectangular based on transparent pixel and in the end to obtain this:
[image]

The result should be the equivalent of Photoshop function Image -> Trim, Based on transparent pixels, trim away top, bottom, left, right:[image]

How I can accomplish this using my code? The masks will have many shapes and sizes.

Here is my python with opencv code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



#load image with alpha channel.  use IMREAD_UNCHANGED to ensure loading of alpha channel
image = cv2.imread('rama1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)    
poza = cv2.imread("poza1.jpg")

#make images of same size
image = cv2.resize(image, poza.shape[1::-1])

#make mask of where the transparent bits are
trans_mask = image[:,:,3] != 0

#replace areas of transparency with white and not transparent
image[trans_mask] = [0, 0, 0,0]

#new image without alpha channel...
new_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

thresh, image_black = cv2.threshold(new_img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

image_black = cv2.cvtColor(image_black, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)




final = cv2.bitwise_and(poza,poza, mask= image_black)

cv2.imwrite('result before.png', final)

final = cv2.cvtColor(final, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
final[:,:,3] = image_black #Set mask as alpha channel





cv2.imwrite('result.png', final)
cv2.imshow('image.jpeg', final) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084609/how-to-copy-a-image-region-using-opencv-in-python

Comment: Thanks, I found a perfect answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273309/using-opencv-how-to-remove-non-object-in-transparent-image