# Is there a way get all coordinates from the detected object using haar cascade?

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I have used below tutorial to detect object and get coordinates of rectangles that contain object
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/d99/tutorial_js_face_detection.html

But I want to get all coordinates of object (not vector of rectangular coordinates) for object extraction.How can I do that?Is there any function can do that?

For example:
[image]

Comment: can you please post your code. Whatever you have so far?

Comment: i have a similar code above documentation link

Comment: Do you want all the coordinates from the object's contour?

Comment: yes,thank you for your interest.Is there a way get all object coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haar-cascades has been trained to return only the rectangular coordinates of the detected object and not the contour.

But try the following:

1) Create a mask with the rectangular coordinates

2) Mask out just the object region using the Mask image(check cv2.bitwise_and)

3) Edge detection using canny or threshold if it is applicable.

4) Find contours.
You can use cv2.findcontours function, where you can set cv2.findcontours(..,..,method =**CHAIN_APPROX_NONE**) to get all the points lying on the contour.

Comment: I cannot find mask() function on opencv.js for creating a mask on OPENCV.js.Is there any way to do that?I do some research find thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python.But this code not mask rectengular area on opencv.js

Comment: Sorry I am not sure about js. You will need to do more research on that