# Crop an image in multiple rectangles and combine them into one in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, slice

I've been referred to [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python), but my question has a little difference.

This can be a numpy-slicing problem. I know I can do:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("test_image.jpg")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

But what if I need two rectangles with the same y range but non-consecutive x ranges of the original picture? I've tried:

```
crop_img = img[y:y+h, [x1:x1+w1, x2:x2+w2]]
```

What I expected was a rectangular having its height from `y` to `y+h`, and its width from `x1` to `x1+w1` plus `x2` to `x2+w2`, where `x1+w1` doesn't have to be equal to `x2`. Nevertheless I get a `SyntaxError` with "invalid syntax". Is there a way to correctly achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract each part and then concatenate with the help of the [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function of numpy.

```
import numpy as np

v1 = img[y:y+h, x1:x1+w1]
v2 = img[y:y+h, x2:x2+w2]

v = np.concatenate((v1, v2), axis=1)
```

Or:

```
indexes = ((x1, w1), (x2, w2))
v = np.concatenate([img[y: y+h , v1: v1+v2] for v1,v2 in indexes], axis=1)
```

**Another way:**

Creating indexes as lists

```
v = img[y:y+h, list(range(x1, x1+w1)) + list(range(x2, x2 + w2))]
```

Comment: Reminder `w1` must be equal to `w2` for this to work without getting `dtype=object` arrays (which will likely break any follow-on code).  If they aren't you probably just want to output a list of `nD` subarrays instead of a `(n+1)D` array.