# Crop the region inside the rectangular face detection box using the top-left corner and bottom-right corner of rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I want to crop faces which are boxed using cv2.rectangle.

I tried :

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_image, 1.25, 6)
```

but this code is detecting only 1 face for this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQhuk.png) but when I used another code :

```
boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,model="hog")
```

it returned me 3 faces with values top,right,bottom,left but I dont know how to crop an image using these values(top,right,bottom,left). Any help will be appreciated.

I am using:

Python- 2.7

OpenCv- 3.1.0

Comment: Your question is "how to crop an image" and has nothing to do with facial recognition, does it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

Comment: You're right Jonathan! but it is part of "face_recognition". The output of my face recognition is an image with detected face and the recognized name is printed on the boxes but I need to crop the detected face and put the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question, boxes have the top, right, bottom, left values of the detected face, so to crop that area with the given top, right, bottom, left values I used [PIL.Image.crop()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop):

Then the code will be like this:

```
    from PIL import Image
    img = Image.open("path/to/file")       
    crop_pic = img.crop( ( left, top, right, bottom ) )        
    crop_pic.show()
```