# How to make crops from list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, crop, bounding-box

I have a list of n lists like this

```
pixels = [[400, 220, 515, 293], [433, 373, 482, 452], [401, 370, 477, 475]]
```

Each sublist correspond to the Top Left and Bottom Right Points for each crop

I made this code to extract a single crop from the whole list

```
  x1 = min(map(lambda x: x[0], pixels))
  y1 = min(map(lambda x: x[1], pixels))
  x2 = max(map(lambda x: x[2], pixels))
  y2 = max(map(lambda x: x[3], pixels))

  crop = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
 cv2_imshow(crop)
```

How can I make n crops from n sublists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54885575/14653627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope It will work

```
import cv2
pixels = [[400, 220, 515, 293], [433, 373, 482, 452], [401, 370, 477, 475]]
for i in pixels:
    img = cv2.imread(r"img _path")
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = i
    crop = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Comment: Some comments explaining your solution would be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked but the way to organize the points is as follows: x1,y1,x2,y2 = i