# How do I get the ROI coordinates based on my prediction?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

I am using SVM to predict my ROI, I trained SVM and now in testing phases, it's giving me output with labels in the form of 1 and 0.

I am trying that if SVM predicts `1` mean image contains eyebrow, now I want that it should be rectangle around the eyebrow because the algorithm is predicting based on the eyebrow. How can I do this?
Below is the code I use for prediction.

```
h_og = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
histogram = h_og.compute(photo)
arr.append(histogram)
arr = np.float32(arr)
result = svm.predict(arr)
```

Now the result is in the form of number or label. How I can draw a rectangle on that ROI of testing image.

```
Positive data: image with eyebrows
Negative data: images not containing eyebrow
Testing data: Full face of the person
```

If I have to use `detectMultiScale()` with it how I will use it with the above logic.

Code use for training purpose

```
sam = []
lab = []    
# Get positive samples
for filename in glob.glob('D:\*.png'):
    im = cv2.imread(filename, 1)
    h_og = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hist = h_og.compute(im)
    sam.append(hist)
    lab.append(1)

# Get negative samples
for file in glob.glob('D:\\*.png'):
    im = cv2.imread(file, 1)
    im = cv2.resize(img, (240, 160))
    h_og = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hist = h_og.compute(im)
    sam.append(hist)
    lab.append(0)

# Convert objects to Numpy Objects
sam = np.float32(sam)
lab = np.array(lab)


# Shuffle Samples
rand = np.random.RandomState(321)
shuffle = rand.permutation(len(sam))
sam = sam[shuffle]
lab = lab[shuffle]    


svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
#svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_RBF)
cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR
# svm.setDegree(0.0)
svm.setGamma(5.383)
# svm.setCoef0(0.0)
svm.setC(2.67)
# svm.setNu(0.0)
# svm.setP(0.0)
# svm.setClassWeights(None)

svm.train(sam, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, lab) 
svm.save('file.xml')
```

More Explanation:

If my image contains eyebrow, my SVM prediction is successfully returning me `1` But after that I want it to display that image the below way, the rectangle should be on the coordinates based on which SVM predicts `1`

[image]

Above image is just a sample image, I am doing it for eyebrow and after prediction, I want to achieve or trying to achieve the output in the above way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

Comment: My data convert it into float form, I am not just simply drawing the rectangle, Its about first I am predicting and wants to draw a rectangle based on that prediction.

Comment: Then you should first ask something like: How do I get the ROI coordinates based on my prediction?

Comment: Yes this comment is better predicting what I am trying to do or asking for help

Comment: Reporting what I said in the chat, negative labels should be -1.

Comment: Even after `-1` its drawing rectangle among whole image, not the eyebrow
Maybe, do I need to change the values of the descriptors `hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((160,320), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svm.predict(arr)` can only predict a single image.

To get coordinates and ROIs you need something that uses this method with different parts of the image at different scales.

So yes, you need to use `detectMultiScale()`. It is a method of `cv2.HOGDescriptor()`, therefore you first need to set `h_og.setSVMDetector(array)` with the SVM supports vectors and the rho that you have trained. You can get them using `svm.getSupportVectors()` and `svm.getDecisionFunction(0)`.

After that, with `found, w = h_og.detectMultiScale(img)` you will have a list of rects (found) containing positive data that you can use to draw your boxes.

---

Try something like this, for example:

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor() 
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load('svm.xml')

sv = svm.getSupportVectors()
rho, alpha, svidx = svm.getDecisionFunction(0)
svm_new = np.append(sv, -rho)
hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)

for file in glob.glob("Testing\\*.jpg"): 
    img = cv2.imread(file, 1) 
    img = cv2.resize(img, (240, 160))
    found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img)

    for (x, y, w, h) in found:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

---

Alternatively, try following [this example](https://answers.opencv.org/question/56655/how-to-use-a-custom-svm-with-hogdescriptor-in-python/). Save the model of the SVM using this:

```
svm.save("svm.xml")
tree = ET.parse('svm.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

SVs = root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[-2].getchildren()[0] 
rho = float( root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[-1].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[1].text )
svmvec = [float(x) for x in re.sub( '\s+', ' ', SVs.text ).strip().split(' ')]
svmvec.append(-rho)
pickle.dump(svmvec, open("svm.pickle", 'w'))
```

In order to do this, you need to import pickle and ElementTree of XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pickle
```

And then load it and use it with this:

```
svm = pickle.load(open("svm.pickle"))
hog.setSVMDetector( np.array(svm) )

found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img)
```

Comment: Do we need to use `h_og.setSVMDetector(svm)` after the prediction part or in training part

Comment: `h_og.detectMultiScale(img)` is the actual prediction part, so you need to set the SVM before doing this command.

Comment: I have edited the post, you cannot put the instance of the SVm in setSVMDetector(); you must put support vectors and rho there.

Comment: `svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load('svm.xml')`
`sam = []`
`for file in glob.glob("Testing\\*.jpg"):
    img = cv2.imread(file, 1)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (240, 160))
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((32,64), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
    hist = hog.compute(img)
    sample.append(hist)
    hog.setSVMDetector(array)
sam = np.float32(sam)
res = svm.predict(sam)
del svm
found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img)
print (res)`

Comment: No, you are not initializing "array" in your code.

You need to get Support Vectors from the SVM and put them in the HOGDescriptor, like what you do with a pretrained People Detector (i.e. https://github.com/abhisharma7/FacePoseEstimation/blob/a5a50ecdbe3a139d8c2a4ccec9904bcb1944b421/facepose_detection.py#L153 ).

To get them you can use the related method of the svm instance.

Comment: Try something like the code I just added to the answer. Adapt it for your case, of course.

Comment: I tried `hog.setSVMDetector(svm.getSupportVectors())
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp:1365: error: (-215:Assertion failed) d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function 'cv::_OutputArray::create'`

Comment: Unfortunately, documentation about this argument is very poor.
I forgot to add the decision function, try the updated code on the answer.

Comment: I checked this method last week `rho, alpha, svidx = cv.ml_SVM.getDecisionFunction(0)` its from cv, i am using cv2.

Comment: No, it's from cv2. I only typed it wrong because I copied it from the documentation. It is a method of cv::ml::SVM, therefore you just need to use it with the SVM that you have loaded.
`svm.getDecisionFunction(0)`

Comment: cv2 simply means that you are using the C++ library. And as you can see [there](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/include/opencv2/ml.hpp#L791) this method is wrapped (CV_WRAP) for the use with python, and it's C++.

Comment: What type of error do you have? Could you post your new code?

Comment: `hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\hog.cpp:115: error: (-215:Assertion failed) checkDetectorSize() in function 'cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector'`

Comment: If I comment `#hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)` this line, code run without error but not getting the required output,

Comment: Wait, you are using the code of my answer? If so, you must set the parameters of HOGDescriptor like the ones you used in the training. So use hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor() instead of my example.

Comment: I used the hog=cv2.HOGDescriptor() both ways with argument and without argument but still no luck !!!

Comment: Mmh strange, I don't know, try the alternative that I wrote then.

Comment: Do I need to change any code in my learning part `hist = h_og.compute(im)
    sam.append(hist)
    lab.append(0)`

Comment: No, you don't need to change your training.

Comment: It is running but not drawing a rectangle on the region of interest but drawing on the whole image even negative

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197367/discussion-on-answer-by-doch88-how-do-i-get-the-roi-coordinates-based-on-my-pred).