# How to extract bottom part from engineering drawing image using python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, ocr

My input image

[image: My input image]

To extract highlighted part

[image: To extract highlighted part]

My desired output

[image: My desired output]

Please someone help and give me a suggestion. My images looks like this. This is just sample one. I need to crop the bottom template part and do OCR. I have attached my desire output picture. Please have a look. How to implement it using python?

PS: The sheet size will differ and there may the chance of template to dislocate. but mostly it will be in lower left corner

Comment: Does this answer your question (at least for the cropping)? [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

Comment: i need to identify that template part programmatically and crop it

Answer (score 7):

Here's a potential approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** We convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, then Otsu's threshold
2. **Fill in potential contours.** We iterate through contours and filter using contour approximation to determine if they are rectangular.
3. **Perform morphological operations.** We morph open to remove non-rectangular contours using a rectangular kernel.
4. **Filter and extract desired contour.** Find contours and filter using contour approximation, aspect ratio, and contour area to isolate the desired contour. Then extract using Numpy slicing.

---

1. Binary image

[image]

2. Filled in contours

[image]

3. Morphological operation to remove non-rectangular contours

[image]

4. Desired contour highlighted in green

[image]

Extracted ROI

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Grayscale, blur, and threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Fill in potential contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Remove non rectangular contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (40,10))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

# Filtered for desired contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
    area = cv2.contourArea(approx)
    if len(approx) == 4 and w > h and aspect_ratio > 2.75 and area > 45000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)
        ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Excellent answer/approach!

Comment: Careful here, because `ROI` is not defined outside the `if`/`else` and `for` loop. I f there are no contours found or all contours are filtered, attempting to write `ROI` will result in a error.