# Splitting Very large images into overlapping boxes/blocks/tiles/sections, python, OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, split

I have very large images 10k by 10k that i need to split into overlapping boxes as shown below. Id like the box to be of size X by Y and I need to stride(distance the box moves across the image in pixels) that box across the screen a given distance. Then Save each individual box section as its own image file. Id like to be able to change the X and Y values and the stride value. I'm using Python and have OpenCV
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your efforts

Comment: Search for numpy slicing on Google or this forum to crop one tile. You will likely have to write a loop over your image for each tile you want doing your own computations of the offsets for the top left corner along with your fixed width and height values. See for example the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python using `crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]` Then write that tile to disk

Answer (score 2):

Here is function, that splits image with overlapping from all sides.
On the borders it will be filled with zeros.

What it essentially does: it creates a bigger image with zero padding, and then extract patches of size `window_size+2*margin` with strides of `window_size`.
(You may want to adjust it to your needs)

```
def split(img, window_size, margin):

    sh = list(img.shape)
    sh[0], sh[1] = sh[0] + margin * 2, sh[1] + margin * 2
    img_ = np.zeros(shape=sh)
    img_[margin:-margin, margin:-margin] = img

    stride = window_size
    step = window_size + 2 * margin

    nrows, ncols = img.shape[0] // window_size, img.shape[1] // window_size
    splitted = []
    for i in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            h_start = j*stride
            v_start = i*stride
            cropped = img_[v_start:v_start+step, h_start:h_start+step]
            splitted.append(cropped)
    return splitted
```

Running this

```
img = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
out = split(img, window_size=2, margin=1)
```

will return

```
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  8.,  9., 10.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  0.],
        [ 9., 10., 11.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  8.,  9., 10.],
        [ 0., 12., 13., 14.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 5.,  6.,  7.,  0.],
        [ 9., 10., 11.,  0.],
        [13., 14., 15.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])]
```