# Output a specific Video Area with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to analyze a specific Area in a Video. Is there a way to set the size of frame1 to a specific Area? With cap.read() for Example?

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

    while True:
        # Capture each Frame
        ret, frame1 = cap.read()

        cv2.imshow("Capture", frame1)

        q = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if q == ord("q"):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you for taking the Time

Comment: You are meaning to crop a part of area from the frame, your answer is already in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python) All you need is cropping the area in each loop

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thanks for the help. I will try it immediately