# Crop features detected in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to crop out features from a photo using opencv and haven't quite been able to find anything that helps to do so. I have photos in which I am trying to crop out rivets from metal panels to create a dataset of rivets that focus in on just the rivets. I have been able to use feature detection and feature matching using Orb to match features but I am unsure of how to then crop out those features. Ideally each photo should provide me with multiple cropped out photos of the rivets. Does anyone have any experience with anything such as this?

Comment: Maybe you can provide a sample image and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

For template matching with OpenCV, you can use template matching (which is nicely described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html))

If your template is skewed, rotated, etc. in the photo, you can use [feature homography](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

For cropping the part of the image, you can look at this [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python).