# Extract eyes from haarcascade

Tags: python, opencv

I know how to identify a face and the eyes, with opencv and haarcascade. But how can I crop or get only the eyes from webcam capture? Just one, or even the both, so I can use as a new frame in imshow...

Answer (score 0):

See on this post:

[How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Your "img[y:y+h, x:x+w]" is just the output from your haarcascade. Maybe you recieve multiple output so you have to choose one.

Answer (score 0):

After detect face you can do this.

```
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
for ex, ey, ew, eh in eyes:
    roi = roi_color[ey:ey + ew, ex:ex + eh]
```

Then can show roi using cv2.imshow().

Answer (score 0):

The [haarcascade_eye.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml) and [haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml) link file

```
import cv2

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_eye.xml")
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

#load image saved in the same directory
img = cv2.imread("your_image.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for f in faces:
    x, y, w, h = [ v for v in f ]
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
    alt_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    alt_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(alt_gray)

eye_crop = []
for f in eyes:
    x, y, w, h = [ v for v in f ]
    cv2.rectangle(alt_color, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)

    # Define the region of interest in the image  
    eye_crop.append(alt_gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])

for eye in eye_crop:
    cv2.imshow('eye',eye)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```