# How can I solve ` cv2.dnn.blobFromImage (frame) error for cropped images`?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-71670poj\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:371: error: (-215:Assertion failed) image.depth() == blob_.depth() in  function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::blobFromImages'`

This error is raised when I run the following code:

```
crop = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
img_blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(crop)
```

Comment: numpy indexing is `frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]` unless you do something very strange

Comment: Actually, it sounds that the order is inverted

Comment: You also likely need a `dtype='uint8'` `ddepth=np.uint8` or `.astype(np.uint8)` somewhere on your image import.  Can't tell from here, not enough code pasted to see.

Comment: yea, numpy inverts [col, row].  Read the comments here --  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15589825/3342050

Comment: Thanks. I croped muy image because I need only that specific area. What do you mean by using `dtype='uint8' ddepth=np.uint8 or .astype(np.uint8)`?

Comment: The crop is working fine. The error is raised here: `img_blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(crop)`

Comment: ignore the uint8 stuff. your image is likely already loaded in the right bit depth. what shape of input does your network expect?

Comment: numpy indexing is from outer dimension to inner dimension. the outer dimension is rows, the next one is pixels in a row, and only if you have a color image the last dimension is colors in a pixel. that is the customary indexing of matrices.

Comment: I have a gray scale image and my networ is expecting 300*300, but I don't know the exact size from the crop because it depends on an are where I find a person. That's to say the coordinates x, y, w, h you're seeing there are someone's coordinates on the frame

Comment: I just found the solution now. Let me show below. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solutions guys!

```
crop = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] #Cropping the original image to use only desired coordinates
if (crop.shape) > (300, 300):
   crop = cv.resize(crop, (300, 300)) #resize only if the crop is larger than required size
img_blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(crop) #This model requires 300*300 images since I'm using it with res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000
```