# How to crop an image based on its coordinates in Python Opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, crop

I am drawing a cv2 rectangle by using below line

```
cv2.rectangle(rightImg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Now values are

```
x = 93
y = 62
w = 6
h = 3
```

Now I want to crop that part of the rectangle. Does below line of code make sense:

```
cropImg = rightImg[y:x, y+h:x+w]
```

or

```
cropImg = rightImg[y+h:x+w, y:x]
```

I have tried both of the above but it's not cropping the exact area. What can I try next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

Comment: and please review [ask]. I would have expected any search at all to have turned up suitable answers.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
cropImg=rightImg[y:y+h,x:x+w].
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered here:
[How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

```
crop_img = rightImg[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Be careful of marked as duplicates.

Comment: that is identical to an existing answer, with some superfluous fluff added

Answer (score -1):

It may look a bit weird but you have to write the y coordinates first.

```
cropImg = rightImg[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

It will crop the image at where the rectangle is.

Comment: that is identical to an existing answer.