# Iterate over an image directory, crop the images and save to a new directory

Tags: python, opencv

I have a an image directory I have loaded into a dataframe with annotations coordinates, I am trying to crop the images according to the coordinates (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) and save them into a new dataframe but keep getting an error.

This is the code I have so far:

Here is the df I have

| File_Path | xmin | xmax | ymin | ymax | filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /MyDrive/Brand_Logos/img1.jpg | 100 | 200 | 100 | 200 | img1.jpg |
| /MyDrive/Brand_Logos/img2.jpg | 200 | 300 | 200 | 300 | img2.jpg |
| /MyDrive/Brand_Logos/img3.jpg | 200 | 300 | 200 | 300 | img3.jpg |

here is the code I am trying to use to parse all the files and save them to a new directory

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import cv2

df = pd.read_csv('annotations.csv')

src_path = '/MyDrive/Brand_Logos/'

if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(src_path,'imageProcessDir')):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(src_path,'imageProcessDir'))

dest_path = src_path+'imageProcessDir'

for index, row in df.iterrows():
 filename = row['filename']
    xmin = row['xmin']
    xmax = row['xmax']
    ymin = row['ymin']
    ymax = row['ymax']
    xmin = int(xmin)
    xmax = int(xmax)
    ymin = int(ymin)
    ymax = int(ymax)
    image = cv2.imread(src_path+row['filename'])
    crop = image((xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax))
    cv2.imwrite(dest_path+"/"+filename+ "_" +'cropped'+".jpg", crop)
```

I have a feeling that the cv2 or the crop variable are not working properly, what am I missing?

Comment: What is exactly the error you get?

Comment: TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
on "crop = image((xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax))" line

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the correct way to [crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python) the image, you should do like this:

```
crop = image[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting another Error with error: 
OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Comment: I guess, you have wrong borders in your dataframe that makes it an empty image, you can check on which image it happens

Comment: Thanks, found the issue and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the image array with `image((xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax))`, instead of slicing `image[ymin:ymax, xmin: xmax]`.

In your case, if I want to read and save the image with 3 channels, I would do the following:

```
image = cv2.imread(src_path+row['filename'])
crop = image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
```