# When getting an ROI from a numpy array (opencv image) why does img[y0:y1, x0:x1] seem to use an inconsistent range of indicies?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

OpenCV uses numpy arrays in order to store image data.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084609/how-to-copy-a-image-region-using-opencv-in-python) question and accepted answer I was told that to access a subregion of interest in an image, I could use the form `roi = img[y0:y1, x0:x1]`.

I am confused because when I create an numpy array in the terminal and test, I don't seem to be getting this behavior.  Below I want to get the roi `[[6,7], [11,12]]`, where `y0 = index 1, y1 = index 2`, and `x0 = index 0, x1 = index 1`.

[image]

Why then do I get what I want only with `arr[1:3, 0:2]`?  I expected to get it with `arr[1:2, 0:1]`.

It seems that when I slice an n-by-n ndarray[a:b, c:d], a and c are the expected range of indicies 0..n-1, but b and d are indicies ranging 1..n.

Answer (score 10):

In your posted example numpy and cv2 are working as expected.  [Indexing or Slicing in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing), just as in python in general, is 0 based and of the form `[a, b)`, i.e. not including `b`.

Recreate your example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
>>> arr
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

So the statement `arr[1:2, 0:1]` means get the value(s) at `row=1` (row 1 up to but not including 2) and `column=0` (we expect `6`):

```
>>> arr[1:2, 0:1]
array([[6]])
```

Similarly for `arr[1:3, 0:2]` we expect rows 1,2 and columns 0,1:

```
>>> arr[1:3, 0:2]
array([[ 6,  7],
       [11, 12]])
```

So if what you want is the region `[[a, b], [c, d]]` to include b and d, what you really need is:

```
[[a, b+1], [c, d+1]]
```

Further examples:

Suppose you need all columns but just rows 0 and 1:

```
>>> arr[:2, :]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Here `arr[:2, :]` means all rows up to, but not including 2, followed by all columns `:`.

Suppose you want every other column, starting at column index 0 (and all rows):

```
>>> arr[:, ::2]
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [16, 18, 20],
       [21, 23, 25]])
```

where `::2` follows the `start:stop:step` notation (where stop is not inclusive).