# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QueryFrame'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to test to decode a qr code real time using python and **openCV 3.0**.But now I am getting an error message on my terminal. I tried to search on the internet but I still unable to solve it. Can I know whats the error.

This is my Python code:

```
import cv2 as cv

import zbar

def scanner_procces(frame,set_zbar):    
    set_width = 100.0 / 100
    set_height = 90.0 / 100

    coord_x = int(frame.width * (1 - set_width)/2)
    coord_y = int(frame.height * (1 - set_height)/2)
    width = int(frame.width * set_width)
    height = int(frame.height * set_height)

    get_sub = cv.GetSubRect(frame, (coord_x+1, coord_y+1, width-1, height-1))

    cv.Rectangle(frame, (coord_x, coord_y), (coord_x + width, coord_y + height), (255,0,0))

    cm_im = cv.CreateImage((get_sub.width, get_sub.height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
    cv.ConvertImage(get_sub, cm_im)
    image = zbar.Image(cm_im.width, cm_im.height, 'Y800', cm_im.tostring())

    set_zbar.scan(image)
    for symbol in image:
            print '\033[1;32mResult : %s symbol "%s" \033[1;m' % (symbol.type,symbol.data)

    cv.ShowImage("webcam", frame)
    cv.WaitKey(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cv.namedWindow("webcam", cv.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    set_zbar = zbar.ImageScanner()
    while True:
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        scanner_procces(frame,set_zbar)
```

This is the error code:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QueryFrame'
```

This is the traceback message:

```
init done 
opengl support available 
 select timeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "realtimetestwebcam.py", line 38, in <module>
    scanner_procces(frame,set_zbar)
  File "realtimetestwebcam.py", line 9, in scanner_procces
    coord_x = int(frame.width * (1 - set_width)/2)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'width'
```

Is it the error because of the opencv version? Thank you.

Comment: Now its saying no module named cv

Answer (score 0):

When you use `cv2` you should use

```
cv2.VideoCapture.read
```

instead of `QueryFrame`. For more info see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).
You can try this code

```
capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)
set_zbar = zbar.ImageScanner()
while True:
    _,frame = capture.read()
```

**Updated**

This error message

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'width'

you get because that changed the format of the return value. With **cv** `frame` was an object with some type, and with **cv2** `frame` is `np.ndarray`. Instead of `width` attr you can get its dimensions with `shape` [method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape). Migration from **cv** to **cv2** is not simple process and requires rewriting of a part of the code.

Comment: well now the error shows inside the scanner_process() . The error now is `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'width'`

Comment: @raaj5671 Return format of `capture.read()` differ from `QueryFrame`. Please, check corrected answer

Comment: now i am getting this error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'width'
`

Comment: i have added the traceback message on my question now

Comment: @raaj5671 You trying to add it to my answer. Please, add it to your question

Comment: I am sorry about that. I accidentally add in your answer. Well now i have updated it

Comment: well i just have to add the shape method is it?

Comment: @raaj5671 `shape` method returns tuple. `frame` is 2D array -> this tuple will contains two elements - width and height. Try replace `frame.width` with `frame.shape[0]`.

Comment: well now the error is showing for the height attribute so do i have to use `frame.shape[0]` or `frame.shape[1]`. I am so sorry I am too new to this opencv world.

Comment: @raaj5671 Try to use `frame.shape[0]` instead of width and `frame.shape[1]` instead of height

Comment: @raaj5671 If you want migrate to cv2 from cv you need to carefully read the documentation and manually rewrite your code. Or, probably, solution described in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084609/how-to-copy-a-image-region-using-opencv-in-python) will help you.

Comment: i tried to follow the link you post me just now but now i am getting this error `ImportError: No module named cv` Well according to the answer from the link i change my import to `import cv2.cv`

Comment: @raaj5671 Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215102/installing-opencv-for-python-on-ubuntu-getting-importerror-no-module-named-cv2)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the python-opencv package

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

That solved my whole problem. Thanks to kvorobiev for helping me all the way.