# How to translate circular cropped area in same image using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, translate-animation

#### Original Image

[image]

#### Expected Output.

[image]

I am using this code for translating a specific part into the same image, but output is not changing,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('eye0.jpg', 0)
rows, cols = img.shape

roi = img[200: 300, 360: 450]

M = np.float32([[1, 0, 100], [0, 1, 50]])
dst = cv.warpAffine(roi, M, roi.shape)

cv.imshow('img', img)
cv.imshow('img', dst)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I see no changes from original image. How can I do so? Moreover, as an openCV newbie I would like to know which function should I use/explore here to get my purpose served?

Answer (score 1):

`Copy()` function can help you instead of `warpAffine()`. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741980/copy-and-paste-region-of-image-in-opencv) also:

Here is output and code:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('eye.jpg', 1)
#rows, cols = img.shape

roi = img[80: 100, 140: 160]

img2 = img.copy()

img2[95:115, 140:160]=roi

cv.imshow('img', img)
cv.imshow('imaag', img2)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How to crop round part. Also not trying to copy instead trying to move.

Comment: If you copy something to another place, it looks like moving? Thats what I understood by looking at  your expected output. I cropped as rectangle. There is no function to crop as a circle.

Answer (score 1):

**Image after warp affine tranformation... but for circling the part it seem difficult..
**[image: Image out put after warp affine[][image: this is after warp affine and for circle thing it is bit difficult .[1]]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('eye.jpg')
roi = img[78: 100, 130: 160]
M = np.float32([[1, 0, 6], [0, 1, 4]])
dst = cv.warpAffine(roi, M, (30, 22))
img[80:102, 132:162] = dst
cv.imwrite("newimage.jpg",img)
cv.imshow('img', img)
cv.imshow('img1',dst)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How to crop round part. Also not trying to copy instead trying to move.

Comment: What do you mean by "not trying to copy instead trying to move"? In your expected output it looks like roi is copied and pasted in the same image.