# How to display YOLO predictions on Grafana?

Tags: python, grafana, yolo, yolov8

I am trying to display my YOLO predictions directly on my grafana dashboard/graph. My model takes a picture of the grafana graph as input and detects the various graph patterns that correspond to different categories. I would like to use the graph shown inside the webpage as input and display the predictions directly on the same graph inside the same webpage. Ideally I need something able to draw bounding boxes directly on the webpage/screen, based on the results given by my YOLO model.

I have no idea how to do this, nor what tools could be appropriate.

I hope it is clear, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

What are you using as your YOLO framework?  I'm going to assume Darknet.  When you get the YOLO results, they consist of a class ID, and the coordinates.  What you'll want to do is use standard OpenCV calls to extract those areas from the original image.  Whether you draw the bounding boxes and the labels on top is up to you.

There are libraries that will help you do this.  [DarkHelp](https://github.com/stephanecharette/DarkHelp) is one such library, available for both Linux and Windows.  It has many options that let's you choose how the bounding boxes and labels are drawn.  For example, see the documentation for `annotation_shade_predictions()` that [lets you control how much shading is applied](https://www.ccoderun.ca/darkhelp/api/classDarkHelp_1_1Config.html#a5b3cf9bfb0c24d99f1d98fc852f6d5be).  (I'm the author of DarkHelp.)

With [OpenCV's usual RoI methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58177717/13022), you can extract portions of images and save them to re-use elsewhere.  Thus, from the YOLO results you take the bits of images you want to keep, save them to a temporary file, and then you can display them elsewhere on a web page for example, or pass them into some other API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using ultralytics. I managed to implement a solution using openCV by grabbing the region of interest on the browser's window, and opening another python window to display the results. However I would like to integrate and display the results directly on the grafana graph, kinda like a plugin or something